# How to Group By on Columns in datatable in Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-3.0

```
    var res3 = dtPriorityMatrix.AsEnumerable()                
    .GroupBy(hour => hour.Field<int>("Hour"))
    .OrderBy(item => item.Key)
    .Select(item => new { Hour = item.Key });
```

I have a data table with 5 columns and around 200+ rows of data. One has hours (0-23) and others are Priority 1, Priority 2 and so on till Priority 4. I need to extract number of items of each priority for every hour. I need help with the Linq query as it is not my strong field. Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. Please provide [mcve], at minimum data table definition, sample data and sample result format with values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group by both columns. something like this

```
var query = source.GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2 });
```

so your code will be

```
 var res3 = dtPriorityMatrix.AsEnumerable()                
    .GroupBy(hour =>new { hour= hour.Field<int>("Hour"), priority=hour.Field<int>("Priority")} )

    .Select(item => new {count=item.count(), Hour = item.Key.hour, priority = item.Key.priority});\
```

**edit**

**Reply to your comment:**

when you have your results in a list, you can write it in anyway that you want.
the out put of the query is a list that contains hour, priority and count. 
if you want it in 3 lines of string

```
string hLine="";
string pLine="";
string countLine="";

foreach(var item in res3)
{
hLine+= item.hour+" ";
pLine+= item.prioriy+" ";
countLine+= item.count+" ";
}
```

if you want to have them in a table or anything, use the same approach for filling your tables items

Comment: I want output in a tabular format. Something like this

Hours-> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Priority 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Priority 2 2 0 2 2 5 3 4 3 3 4 3 6 1
Priority 3 2 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 3 6 4 9 6
Priority 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 3 3

Comment: I got your point. Thats not what I was looking for but thanks for putting me in right direction. Thanks

Comment: Happy that I could help